# Is game theory a part of math?

Tags: game-theory

I'm going to write project paper for my course, "The History of Math". My field is 'game theory'.

However, I'm in doubt that game theory is really part of math, since it comes from economics (for me).

My questions are:

1. Is game theory a part of math?
2. What are some papers that heavily use game theory and involve some real math calculations?

Comment: What does it mean to you for a field to be "part of math"?  Look up Nash's "Non-cooperative Games" -- looks pretty mathy.

Comment: Useful mathematics is still mathematics.

Comment: What do you mean by "real math calculations?" The heart of mathematics is not calculations, but rigorous proof.

Comment: If you have any doubts, read [this](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~zamir/documents/General.pdf).

Comment: @AndréNicolas In my opinion math is an interesting field, but not very applicable to real life. Game theory flips that around entirely, so I fully agree with you.

Comment: I am not very familiar with it myself, but you might want to look up selection principles in topology.

Comment: Some games build on [surreal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number#Games).

Comment: @LeeSleek In my opinion real life is an interesting field, but not very applicable to math.

Comment: @proximal I'd think Archimedes with his method of treating mechanical problems (to find mathematical theorems) would beg to differ.

Comment: [Here's one](http://www.princeton.edu/mudd/news/faq/topics/Non-Cooperative_Games_Nash.pdf).

Comment: Are there any papers that involve some *fake* math calculations?

Comment: @Alexander -- thanks for the link to Nash's thesis. A fascinating document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question #1:
Well, I expect some people would say that math is a part of game theory :-).
But certainly some areas of game theory are highly mathematical.

The math subject classification system of the American Mathematical Society lists Game Theory as one of their categories: [link here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/msc/msc2010.html?t=91-XX&s=&btn=Search&ls=s)

Question #2:
Try [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444851844) . There are many other similar ones.

Comment: And, doesn't the fact that I answered the question disprove the vote-to-close assertion that is "cannot reasonably be answered"?? I guess you could argue that my answer is not "reasonable". I would disagree, of course.